# Compiling RAD Studio 2010 project using SYSTEM account does not place BPL files under %BDSCOMMONDIR%. Any other account does

Tags: msbuild, c++builder-2010, rad-studio

RAD Studio 2010 project build using MSBuild works fine when I build it locally. Subprojects that build **BPL** files end up under **C:\Users\Public\Documents\RAD Studio\7.0** like it's supposed to since no other output directory is set.

When building using TeamCity it all fell apart. Complaining it could not find **BPL** files generated by subprojects. Looking in the directory where it should end up nothing was created there. Instead, the **BPL** files ended up in the projects directory.

After scratching my head, checking environment variables etc and all the **BDSCOMMONDIR** and similar variables are set etc it dawned on me that the TeamCity build Agent was running as the **SYSTEM** account. I opened a command prompt as the **SYSTEM** account using

> PsExec.exe -i -s cmd.exe

I checked environment variables again, they all existed for the account. Started a build locally as SYSTEM and the same issue. BPL files in the project directory instead of the default folder, subsequent projects not finding the **BPL** files since they look in the default location, build failed.

But why?

Using another user it compiles fine and running the TeamCity build agent as that user enables TeamCity to finish the build correctly to.

Comment: The IDE's output folders are configured on a per-user basis, as are environment variables. That is why the paths are not as expected when running under the `SYSTEM` account.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: Strange that selecting "All users" when installing doesn't set it in a way that all users can use it. Would this be solved by starting the IDE once with the SYSTEM account?